# move My Cart block to header ONLY with local.xml

Tags: cart, xml, header, local.xml

Is it possible to move the Cart block from the sidebar to the header, ONLY with the local.xml file?

This is not working:

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>cart_sidebar</alias></action>
</reference>
<reference name="header">
    <action method="insert"><blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

No. the `header.phtml` also needs a `getChildHtml` call.
An option would be to add it to `<reference name="content">` and use CSS to position the block on the header.

Your `local.xml` would look something like this

```
<default>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_header" template="checkout/cart/header.phtml" before="-">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
            <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
<reference name="right">
   <remove name="cart_sidebar"/>
</reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working... :(

Comment: can you give a little more information? What's happening exactly. could it be cache? might it be a templating issue?